# why @1.first_column's value is always 0

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I want to report error message , the column and the line when problems occur.yylineno is ok,work well,but @1.first_column's value is always 0 ,no matter how I modify test text.

the yacc file snippet：

```
set:SET PARENTHESIS reference EQUAL expression CLOSE_PARENTHESIS {$$ = set_directive($3,$5); }
|error {yyerrok; yyclearin;printf("column is %d",@1.first_column);yyerror("Set directive error!",@1.first_column);YYABORT;}
;
```

I have no search to the similar problems,please help me!

Answer (score 1):

`flex` doesn't fill in the column fields; you have to do it yourself. There's an example in John Levine's highly-recommended book `Flex and Bison`; fortunately, the relevant section is (currently) available as an O'Reilly [excerpt](http://oreilly.com/linux/excerpts/9780596155971/error-reporting-recovery.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `yylloc` in your lexical analyzer?  If not, then you won't get to see anything other than `1` for the values you mention.